# Django filter a floatfield with a value equals or less

Tags: django

I need to filter all the values ​​of the radius less than the data value but django querys only allows me to check if they are equal

How can I implement something like this
response =item.objects.filter(radius<data)

```
def home (request , data=None):
    response =item.objects.filter(radius=data)
    response_vector=[]
    for response in response:
        response_vector.append(response)
    if len(response_vector)>0:
       return HttpResponse(response_vector[0].items) 
    else:
        return HttpResponse(401)
```

I do not want to do something like this:

```
def home (request , data=None):
    response=[]
    for x in range(0, data):
        response.append(item.objects.filter(radius=x))
    response_vector=[]
    for response in response:
        response_vector.append(response)
    if len(response_vector)>0:
       return HttpResponse(response_vector[0].items) 
    else:
        return HttpResponse(401)
```

Comment: You have asked similar question yesterday use __lte https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#gt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`lte`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#lte) lookup

```
esponse = item.objects.filter(radius__lte=data)
```